# Is it possible to support SOCKS5 for certain hosts transparently?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, socks5

I have SSH access to a jump box on my work. This jump box gives access to the complete network infrastructure at work. This is great to work from home.

I am able to run a SOCKS5 proxy on the jump box (via `ssh -D`) and successfully managed to configure my browser to use that SOCKS5 proxy for work hosts (via https://getfoxyproxy.org). Foxyproxy seems to forward DNS requests to that SOCKS5 proxy, so all is working fine.

While this all works fine, I am wondering if it is possible to let my system use the SOCKS5 for work-related traffic in a more transparent manner. It's quite exhausting to figure out for each application I use if it supports SOCKS5 and if so, how.

More concrete, is there a way to configure my system in such way that it will automatically route traffic via the SOCKS5 for predefined hosts?

I know there are tools such as proxychains (see https://github.com/haad/proxychains), but this is not what I am after. This routes all traffic of an **application** to the proxy, while I want to route all traffic to a **host** to the proxy, if that makes sense.

Is this possible?

For your information, I asked a related question regarding DNS requests here: [Forward DNS request to my work's jump server](https://superuser.com/questions/1456720/forward-dns-request-to-my-works-jump-server). Combining this question with the DNS question, I hopefully end up with a fully transparent way of interacting with work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tunnel all of my network traffic through SSH?](https://superuser.com/questions/62303/how-can-i-tunnel-all-of-my-network-traffic-through-ssh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *technically* possible, though note that SOCKS only supports TCP tunnels (and in *rare* cases UDP). Anything else would have to be dropped.

If you use Linux, you can use iptables to redirect specific packets to a locally running *transparent proxy,* of which there are several SOCKS-capable ones – Google gives [transocks](https://github.com/cybozu-go/transocks), [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/), [pr0cks](https://github.com/n1nj4sec/pr0cks).

(The Tor-based "Tails" OS does the same trick, but the transparent proxying functionality is now built in to the Tor daemon itself – there is no separate SOCKS layer involved.)

For operating systems which do not have such "transparent proxy" support, it would still be possible but the software could get quite complex – it could create a virtual TUN interface that the packets could be routed to, but it would need to handle the entire client-side TCP protocol on its own, without any help from the OS. (SOCKS doesn't actually relay raw TCP packets, it only relays the data carried inside.)

Comment: Thank you. I will get start experimenting.

Comment: FYI, I tried to get going with redsocks, but am hitting a wall currently. I listed my case here: https://superuser.com/questions/1457781/why-is-redsocks-not-being-used-for-traffic-in-this-dockerized-environment

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look at [`socksify`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify). It might work particularly well if your office proxy uses Dante, but should be fine for other set-ups as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `transocks`. [My IP tables configuration](https://gist.github.com/andersondanilo/a28e7165fa8a9700d8ead20a224ecf44) looks like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Transocks: https://github.com/cybozu-go/transocks

set -e
stty -echoctl

# Point to the transparent socket port (running in an exclusive user)
TRANSOCKS_PORT=12345
TRANSOCKS_USER=transocks

# Redirect all the network of your computer (except transocks user)
REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK=1

# Redirect access point (wifi hotspot)
AP_SUBNET_ENABLED=1
AP_SUBNET_IFACE=ap0
AP_SUBNET_RANGE="192.168.12.0/24"

function action_up()
{
    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Adding iptables chain rules"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -t nat -N TRANSOCKS
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 198.18.0.0/15 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TRANSOCKS_PORT

    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting non-transocks user"
        echo "--------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "-----------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting AP subnet"
        echo "-----------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -I PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -I INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi
}

function action_down()
{
    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "------------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning non-transocks rules"
        echo "------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning AP subnet rules"
        echo "--------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -D INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi

    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Cleaning and removing chain"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -F TRANSOCKS -t nat
    iptables -v -X TRANSOCKS -t nat
}

trap 'action_down' SIGINT

action_up

echo
echo "Hit Ctrl+C to remove the ip table rules"
echo


while :
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question that was asked, it would be good to describe exactly how it solves the problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [TS-Warp](https://github.com/mezantrop/ts-warp/). Work on Linux, *BSD, mac.